# What real-world size is a “square”?

Tags: dnd-4e, battle-map

Does 4E D&D specify what the real-world size of a battlemap "square" is? Reference/citation desired.

Comment: What resources do you have available and what resources have *you* checked? I'm pretty sure this is explicitly stated in one of the rule books.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### A single battlemap square represents a 5 foot by 5 foot space.

From the PHB, p266:

> A 1-inch square on the battle grid represents a 5-foot square in the game world. So a dungeon room that is 40 feet by 50 feet would be 8 squares by 10 squares, which is a huge room but a good size for a busy combat encounter.

Answer (score 5):

This is answered in multiple rule books.

PHB, pg.9

> **Battle Grid or Dungeon Tiles:** Combat in D&D plays out on a grid of 1-inch squares.

PHB, pg.266

> A 1-inch square on the battle grid represents a 5-foot square in the game world.

Rule Compendium, pg.200

> ## Key terms
>
> **battle grid:** The network of 1-inch squares that represents an encounter area.

DMG, pg.7

> **Battle Grid:** A battle grid is very important for running combat encounters, for reasons outlined in the Player’s Handbook. [...] The grid should be marked in 1-inch squares.